# I want to know the behavior of outputType when translating with python gdal

Tags: python, gdal

The input.tif file contains values with pixel values greater than or equal to 255. When I set outputType = gdal.GDT_Byte in gdal.Translate, the pixel value is less than or equal to 255.

What was done by setting outputType?

If pixel values greater than 255 are simply converted to 255?

```py
gdal.Translate('output.tif','input.tif',outputType=gdal.GDT_Byte)
test = gdal.Open('output.tif').ReadAsArray()
print(np.max(test))

# output max is 255
```

I could not find a detailed manual for outputType.

[osgeo.gdal.TranslateOptions](https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.gdal.html#osgeo.gdal.TranslateOptions)

Comment: A Byte (as defined by GDAL) can contain values from 0 to 255, and GDAL clips the values when you convert to the range of that datatype when you convert it.